# Persistence of KAM tori as a function of dimension

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, diophantine-equations, hamiltonian-mechanics

I have tried posting this question in MSE, but I think it might be too technical so I'm trying again here.

In [KAM theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem) one tries to describe the persistence of quasi-periodic motion when an integrable system is perturbed in a non-integrable way. Most physicists thought integrability would be instantaneously destroyed by any infinitesimal perturbation, a result that turned out to be theoretically wrong but, practically, is hard to argue against. The precise and deep statements of KAM theory were valuable for dealing with systems with only a few degrees of freedom, and played an important role in understanding both the classical and the quantum structures of the [helium atom](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Semiclassical_theory_of_helium_atom). However, in the context in which most physicists before Kolmogoroff's proof were referring to, namely the realm of systems with a huge number of degrees of freedom, the KAM theorem remains a result to be ignored: perturbations are indeed assumed to create ergodicity, which is wrong due to the measure of regular regions being non-zero for any perturbation strength. (this troubles some mathematicians, but physicists categorically don't care at all)

What I would like to do is to justify this approach by showing that many degrees of freedom imply less tori survive a perturbation. I have been trying to see this from to the Diophantine condition in the following way. We know that resonant tori are indeed destroyed for any perturbation strength, but they have measure zero so this is irrelevant. Every non-resonant torus can be associated to a somewhat optimal Diophantine constant emerging from the best possible rational approximation to is frequency (i.e. every non-resonant torus is a Diophantine torus). Some tori have "better" constants than others, in the sense that when perturbed they will survive, while others will be destroyed. The condition for survival is that there must exist a vector of integers $k$ such that

$$ \vert k \cdot \omega \vert \gg \frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{\vert k \vert^N} , \qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}^N \setminus \{0\} \, ,$$

where $\varepsilon$ is the perturbation strength, $\omega$ is a vector of frequencies for each circle composing the torus, and $N$ is the number of degrees of freedom. From the above condition, I have the impression that large $N$ would actually render the RHS smaller. I therefore am stuck with the absurd statement that when the number of degrees of freedom increases, the tori become *harder* to destroy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Err, I am not quite sure what you mean, but I will comment Burago, Chen, Ivanov proved miraculously that for an integrable PDE (which has an infinite number of conservations) that there exists at least one perturbation with a positive measure set of positive entropy. This result has not been achieved in finite dimensions and if it ends up being true, would be one of the most outstanding results in dynamics in recent memory.